# PLSQL Date Filter Error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

I have a table with data since 2012. I need to get data in this table from `31 days back` from `given date`. so i wrote below query to get data.

```
select ('[' || work_date || '] ' || field_name || ' - ' ||work_desc) d
from DAILY_WORK
where TO_CHAR(work_date,'DD/MM/YYYY') >= TO_CHAR(to_date('30-Jan-13','dd-MON-yyyy') - (31),'DD/MM/YYYY')
order by work_date desc
```

When i execute this query, it returns data in below dates only.

```
31-AUG-12
31-OCT-12
30-DEC-12
31-DEC-12
```

But actually i need to get data `from 2012-12-30 to 2013-01-30`.

How could i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
select ('[' || to_char(work_date, 'dd-MON-yyyy') || '] ' || field_name || ' - ' ||work_desc) d
from DAILY_WORK
where work_date >= to_date('30-Jan-2013','dd-MON-yyyy') - 31
order by work_date desc
```

Comment: not working.i need to get data `from 2012-12-30 to 2013-01-30`. this returns data older than `2012-12-30`.

Comment: it is correct. but when i execute the query, it returns data older than `2012-12-30`. that is the problem. i don't know whats the issue.

Comment: the query indeed works. I believe it is your string manipulation that did not. See my updated solution (watch out the to_char in the select)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query:

```
select * from DAILY_WORK where work_date >= TRUNC(to_date('01-30-2013','MM/DD/YYYY')) - 31
```

Check date format which tool you are using As per tool i am using date format is 'MM/DD/YYYY'

This query give correct result.You can check.